# UITextView How to display new text above the previous line?

Tags: ios, text, nsstring, uitextview

I am currently trying to, as the title says, display a new line **above** the previous line in a UITextView. I have been unable to find this anywhere on the web and I really need help on this. Here is the code currently inside of my method:

```
[textBox setScrollEnabled:YES];

[textBox setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 170)];

textBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nIts pitch black."];

textBox.text = [textBox.text stringByAppendingString:@"\rYou hear someone in the dark."];
```

Result:
    Its pitch black.
    You hear someone in the dark.

Wanted Result:
    You hear someone in the dark.
    Its pitch black.

Forgive me if I appear unintelligent, I am new to iOS. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 textBox.text = @"\nIts pitch black.";
 textbox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\rYou hear someone in the dark. %@", textbox.text];
```

Hope it helps.